# Average of a pair with respect to a function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, functions, proof-writing

I have $200$ units of good A and $200$ units of good B. For each unit, I assign them an integer price $[1, 2, 3, ... 200]$. Each price can only be assigned to one unit of good A and B. For example, 100 could be the price for the 55th unit of good A but it could not simultaneously be the price of the 99th element of good A. However, 100 could be the price for the 55th unit of good A and simultaneously be the price for the 2nd element of good B.

Out of these $200$ from each good, I randomly pick $20$ of good A and $20$ of good B.

From these $20$ of each, I randomly pair together one unit of good A and one unit of good B, $(a_1, b_1)$ and repeat this to $(a_{20}, b_{20})$. How can I prove that there are **at least $2$ pairs** where the averages of their prices are equal $(\frac{a_1 + b_1}{2} = \frac{a_2 + b_2}{2})$

My thinking:

We can have two functions: $f$ and $g$ where $f$ represents the price for good A and $g$ for good B. I'm thinking that $f$ and $g$ are bijective. How do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can pair any elements of your subsets together, there are 20*20=400 distinct pairs you can make from any two selections. However, the sum of any two integers between 1 and 200 is between 2 and 400, so there are only 399 possible sums. By the pigeonhole principle, for any two selections of 20 elements in A and B there must be at least two possible pairs that have the same sum (and thus average).

Answer (score 0):

This need not be true, unless I'm missing something...

Having the same averages is equivalent to having the same sum; I'll speak to that to avoid having to discuss fractions.

So, the question is whether or not you can choose 20 distinct $a_i\in[1,200]$ and 20 distinct $b_i\in[1,200]$ such that $a_1+b_1,\ldots,a_{20}+b_{20}$ are all distinct.

And that, you most certainly can.  Let $a_1=b_1=1$, $a_2=b_2=2$, etc. Then for each $i$ we have $a_i+b_i=2i$, which clearly is distinct for different choices of $i$.

Comment: Good point in bringing up the equivalence of the sum to the average in this case. The proof is that there's at least 2 pairs. I can think of a counterexample but we only need to find 2 pairs where that's true

Comment: Yes; but to prove the statement, it must be the case that there is NEVER a counterexample.  The presence of an example in which there are no two pairs with the same sum disproves the claim.